# Implementing OOP "interface" with Prototype.js framework

Tags: javascript, oop, interface, prototypejs

We are using Prototype.js framework for OOP. I know you can do class inheritance easily. You can do callbacks easily. So, is there a way to implement an OOP "interface"? Or, do we have to stay with class inheritance?

Comment: Also, is there a better way to implement OOP in javascript?

Comment: Javascript does OOP just fine, if you don't get hung up on trying to do it like Java does.  :)

Comment: Highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710275/does-javascript-have-the-interface-type-such-as-java-interface/3710367#3710367 -- my answer goes a bit into why JS doesn't have Java-style interfaces (and to a degree, why they wouldn't be worth having anyway).