# How to do an in-order traversal of the DOM?

Tags: javascript

I found this ridiculously technical document:

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/traversal.html#Traversal-Document

but did not see how it related to writing actual JavaScript code.

I would guess that I could use basic DOM methods and properties like `eachChild()` and `.children` to do the traversal, but I'm not sure what the best strategy is?

Comment: What is ridiculously technical with `depth first, pre-order traversal, which is equivalent to the order in which the start tags occur in the text representation of the document`?

Comment: What do you want to do? In modern browsers, there are lots of helper APIs to find elements with particular qualities.

Comment: @Handy, `DocumentTraversal` is an interface that provides document-ordered iterators and can be implemented by the `document` instance your browser provides. If your browser supports [document.createNodeIterator()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.createNodeIterator) and [document.createTreeWalker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTreeWalker), then you can indeed access that interface from Javascript.

Comment: JavaScript does not have interfaces, in the programming sense ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710275/does-javascript-have-the-interface-type-such-as-javas-interface

Comment: @Handy, that interface is an abstraction device used by the Javascript implementation you're working with. On the JS side, `document` either implements these methods or it doesn't, and you can check for that.

Comment: ...so like I thought...just a way to group together a bunch of functionality ...

Comment: @Handy, it can also be considered as some kind of contract. Wikipedia even calls them [protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_%28object-oriented_programming%29) now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you get the root node, you only need `firstChild` and `nextSibling`. This is Douglas Crockford's function for that, from his book *JavaScript - The Good Parts*, p. 35:

```
var walk_the_DOM = function walk(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while(node) {
        walk(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

It's meant to traverse the DOM from the given node, and run a callback on each node found. For example:

```
walk_the_DOM(document.body, function(node) {
    console.log(node);
});
```

Comment: This gives you a good example of traversing the DOM: http://javascript.info/tutorial/traversing-dom

Comment: @Handy That's more for browser vendors / implementation providers. In any case, it documents the whole DOM API standards. F.J's answer is based on stuff mentioned there (the `createNodeIterator` function).

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to do this using [`document.createNodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.createNodeIterator):

```
var nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(document.body);
var currentNode;
while (currentNode = nodeIterator.nextNode()) {
    console.log(currentNode);
}
```