# Declare Typescript Interface for non Typescript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to declare a TypeScript interface for a plain JavaScript class?

e.g.

```
function Foo(bar)
{
  this.bar=bar;
}

var x=new Foo("test"); // x is shown as any
```

I'd like to declare an interface for Foo:

```
interface IFoo
{
  bar: string;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to declare it.

```
function Foo(bar: string) : IFoo
{
  this.bar=bar;
}
```

Gives me "'Foo' declared a non-void return type, but has no return expression."

(I don't want to rewrite Foo as a TypeScript class.)

Comment: Maybe similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710275/does-javascript-have-the-interface-type-such-as-javas-interface

Comment: @jsmorph No, this is about TypeScript.

Comment: As @basarat says, separate your JavaScript code from TypeScript code, or convert your JavaScript code into TypeScript (which will compile into a version similar to your original JavaScript code).

Answer (score 4):

You can simply declare it to be a class :

```
declare class Foo{
    bar:string;
    constructor(bar:string);
}

var x=new Foo("test"); // x of type foo
x.bar="lala";
```

Comment: This will not compile - it gives me a `Duplicate identifier 'Foo'.` for `function Foo(bar) {...}`!

Comment: You need to put the JavaScript code in JavaScript. You cannot type in typescript and tell the compiler that this is a class not a function

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to integrate a pure Javascript library with typescript and this did the trick.