# How to define "interface" in js

Tags: javascript

Good day.
My question is quite dumb, I guess, but I'm not familiar enough with the termins, to ask it properly (and to get an answer from Google).
So - please help...

Shortly - I'm trying to create some major class, which will be insanitated by instances, which will describe some methods, and some fields.
Major logick will be implemented in parent class.

So, lets say I have a parent

```
function CRUD_Grid_model(){

  //Settings part
  this.GridElement = "" ;
  this.editModeFlagElement = "" ;
  this.newRowElement = "";
  //Save logicks all lies here.

  this.commit = function (){
    alert("PLEASE REDEFINE COMMIT FUNCTION IN YOUR CODE");
  }
  ;
  //Settings part

  //Some more code.
}
```

And a way I'll use it

```
//Das modell
var JobberCRUD = new CRUD_Grid_model();
JobberCRUD.GridElement = $('#jobbers_dg');
JobberCRUD.editModeFlagElement = $('#jobbers_tb_edit');
JobberCRUD.newRowElement = {jobb_name:'Enter new unique name',jobb_status:'Y'};
JobberCRUD.commit = function (){
  if (this.endEditing()){
    var addrows = this.GridElement.datagrid('getChanges','inserted');
    var remrows = this.GridElement.datagrid('getChanges','deleted');
    var updrows = this.GridElement.datagrid('getChanges','updated');

    console.log(addrows);
    console.log(remrows);
    console.log(updrows);
    //Send changes?
    alert("Got total of " +addrows.length + remrows.length + updrows.length + " rows changed.");                
    //Commit changes at local level
    this.GridElement.datagrid('acceptChanges');
  }
};
```

And, what I'd like to do, is smoething like this

I want a parent.commit function to allow me to do this in child

```
JobberCRUD.commit = function (apdrows,updrows,remrows){
  //Send changes?
  alert("Got total of " +addrows.length + remrows.length + updrows.length + " rows changed.");                
};
```

So, I have no ideas what shoudl I do to achieve that. Please advice me with some tags, what it is at least :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the answer here - essentially interfaces don't exist in Javascript..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710275/does-javascript-have-the-interface-type-such-as-javas-interface

Comment: There's an excellent article on emulating inheritance in javascript on Crockford's website: http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html

Comment: This might be helpful: MDN Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not exactly what you need in JavaScript, but I would tend to use this pattern :

```
function CRUD_Grid_model() {
    ...
    this.onCommit = null;

    this.commit = function (){
        if (this.endEditing()){
            var addrows = this.GridElement.datagrid('getChanges','inserted');
            var remrows = this.GridElement.datagrid('getChanges','deleted');
            var updrows = this.GridElement.datagrid('getChanges','updated');

            if(this.onCommit != null) this.onCommit(addrows,updrows,remrows);

            this.GridElement.datagrid('acceptChanges');
        }
    }
    ...
}

var JobberCRUD = new CRUD_Grid_model();
JobberCRUD.onCommit = function(apdrows,updrows,remrows) {
    alert("Got total of " +addrows.length + remrows.length + updrows.length + " rows changed.");                
};
JobberCRUD.GridElement = ...
```

Comment: Dammint, looks like what I need ) Gone testing.

Comment: Works like a charm, and explains itself elegantly, so I now understand the mechanics.
Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have a built in notion of interfaces. A javascript object effectively "implements an interface" by having all the needed methods defined, but there's no language "interface" construct

Comment: Okay, but your answer doesn't containt anything about - how that can be acheved. Please, re-read the question, I might be using the wrong word. I might be looking for something that is not an interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "extends" like so:

```
Object.prototype.extends = function(clazz) {
    var o = new clazz();
    for (var f in o) {
        if(f === "extends") {
            continue;
        }
        this[f] = o[f];
    }
    this.super = o;
}
```

Now could type something like this:

```
var JobberCRUD = function() {
    this.extends(CRUD_Grid_model);
    var privateFunction = function() {
        //...
    }
    // You probably don't want to do that,
    // but you could override
    this.commit = function() {
        //...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Hope, that helps.

Edit: forgot, that you may call super.commit() then.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have something similar like C# or Java interface or even class with Javascript.

Javascript is just a dynamic scripting language.

Comment: But, as I said - that's not what I'm after.
I want to do something similar to  
    $('dom_object').datagrid.onClick = function(rowIndex){
    //My code, that uses this rowIndex
    }  
that was taken from EasyUI framework, but same approach can be seen in many frameworks.
All I want is to do the same, split getting the values part to parent, and using the values part to instance.