# Creating templates with exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to make template modules, each of which has 3 functions. For example, there can be `module1.js` which will have `exports.function1`, `exports.function2` and `exports.function3`. There will be `module2.js` which also has the exact same functions; just the functionality would differ.

I use WebStorm for development and when I type `exports.`, it gives me the 3 function names as autocomplete suggestions.

My question is, will these functions overwrite each other? Or is it okay to have same function names in different modules?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript have the interface type (such as Java's 'interface')?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710275/does-javascript-have-the-interface-type-such-as-javas-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue if you use the same name: `exports` is, at core, a simple object, and this is perfectly fine:

```
var obj = {a: 1};
var obj2 = {a: 2};
console.log(obj.a + obj2.a); // prints... 3!
```

The reason WebStorm shows the three functions is because it's unable to statically determine which are actually available. If you run the code, you'll confirm it.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, setting `exports = {}` is invalid while setting `module.exports = {}` is fine. Right?

Comment: yes, that's correct! Well, it's not *invalid* per say, but it will not update the outer one

Comment: @LittleChild yes, because the the first example overwrites the existing reference with a new one