# Implementing an interface / plugin approach in JavaScript / ES6

Tags: javascript

I'm building an app in JavaScript (ES6). I'm more familiar with C#, so if my lingo is a bit off, I apologize.

Anyways, in my app, I want to create a service that supports other services. Basically, when my service is created, I want to dynamically load some services that implement my "interface". That "interface" has a single function named "sendMessage". Then, when I call MyService.sendMessage('someMessage'), that message will automatically get sent out via the registered services. I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
const MyService {
  initialize: function() {
    this.services = [];

    // Somehow load services here

    // This function will send the message to the plugins
    this.sendMessage = function(msg) {
      for (let service in services) {
        service.sendMessage(msg);
      }
    };
  }
};
```

The above doesn't work because, the services aren't getting populated in anyway. I know that JavaScript doesn't have an `interface` keyword like C#. For that reason, I know that I need a way to "register" services. My question But, I'm not sure how to do this.

How do I create a service such that a third-party developer can plugin to my service?

Comment: What kind of syntax is `const MyService {...`?

Comment: What should a developer see/ could he do with your class?

Comment: And what do you need interfaces for? You can simply check for properties and if one doesnt exist you can throw an error

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't have `interface` per se, but it sure has classes. (ES6)

So, what you can do is create a base-class such as this:

```
class BaseService {
    constructor(options) {
        // Handle options here
    }

    // Methods

    sendMessage(msg) {
        throw new Error(`sendMessage is not implemented in the base class. 
                         Please override this method in your extended class.`);
    }

    // Other Methods

    get name() {
        // 
    }
}
```

Next, if anyone wants to build a service for your app, like an SMS gateway provider, they can simply `extend` your BaseService class and implement their own `sendMessage` method.

Of course, you cannot stop them from **not** implementing that method.
However, if they don't, an error will be thrown. Which I guess, provides a somewhat Interface like abstraction in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.typescriptlang.org/ for interfaces. 
ES6 'class' doesn't support interfaces, so typescript is your best way, unless you want to develop OOP infra by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Implementation of Interfaces in Javascript as it is a Dynamic language and not strongly typed as c#. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3710367/6007536) answer which explains a work around for your question.

Hope this helps.