# Converting React TS interface to React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm attempting to integrate [this package](https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak) into an app using [this example](https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak-examples/tree/master/examples/react-router). I'm not too familiar with typescript and I see that it uses `interface` in one of the utils (which javascript does not have). I've read [Does JavaScript have the interface type (such as Java's 'interface')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710275/does-javascript-have-the-interface-type-such-as-javas-interface), but I'm not sure this is the same as the one typescript uses.

---

Here's the TS code I am trying to convert:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom'
import type { RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom'

import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web'

interface PrivateRouteParams extends RouteProps {
  component:
    | React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any>>
    | React.ComponentType<any>
}

export function PrivateRoute({
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}: PrivateRouteParams) {
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak()

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        keycloak?.authenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: props.location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}
```

---

Here's what someone suggested for JS:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';

export function PrivateRoute({ component, ...rest }) {
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        keycloak?.authenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/auth',
              state: { from: props.location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

---

Still, I don't think that `<Component />` will work in react.js.

EDIT: Added code

Comment: If i understand correctly, you're writing javascript and want to know how to use the package? You should just need to run `npm install --save @react-keycloak/web`. Code that was written in typescript transpiles to javascript, so it should work seamlessly.

Comment: If you still need help, please provide the code you've tried. Links to code don't cut it, as they'll likely go stale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Router takes a prop `component` with a lowercase `c`.  In order to call a custom component using JSX it **must** have an uppercase name. See the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

The Typescript example code renamed the prop `component` to `Component` when destructuring it.  That allows them to call `<Component />` using JSX.

When converting the code to Javascript you accidentally removed this renaming.  You probably mistook it for a type annotation.

This code should work:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web'

export function PrivateRoute({
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) {
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak()

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        keycloak?.authenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: props.location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}
```